# Obtener registros ordenados por fecha y limitado a 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta SQL que no sé si se pueda en realidad, pero mi propósito es obtener los registros dependiendo de los id's, ordenándolos por fecha más reciente y limitándolos a 1 para en un principio sólo mostrar un registro y ya en otra vista mostrar todos sin el límite.

Hasta ahora tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE idprincipal = 28 || 26 AND idfinal = 26 || 28
ORDER BY sent ASC
```

¿Cómo le puedo poner a esa consulta un `limit 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un problema con la lógica que usas en tu consulta SQL. Usas el operador *o lógico* como si sirviera para seleccionar más de un elemento, cuando eso no es así. Además, debes ordenar de manera descendente para que el primer registro (el que te quedas) sea el mayor y los posteriores sean inferiores a éste.

Para filtrar por varios valores de un campo debes usar el operador [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html).

---

**Una forma correcta de hacerlo sería:**

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE
  idprincipal IN (28, 26)
AND
  idfinal IN (26, 28)
ORDER BY sent DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[Aquí puedes ver una versión en línea.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s1vw8PgtGchtknsctGxPXm/2) Elimina el comentario (`--` del `LIMIT`) para obtener únicamente el más reciente.

---

**Descripción detallada del problema:**

Tal y como puedes ver en la documentación de [orden de operadores](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html) las asociaciones Y (&&) se resuelven antes que las O (||), por lo que tu consulta quedaría:

```
idprincipal = 28 || 26 AND idfinal = 26 || 28
( idprincipal = 28 ) || 26 AND ( idfinal = 26 ) || 28
( idprincipal = 28 ) || ( 26 AND ( idfinal = 26 ) ) || 28
28
```

En la última línea ha quedado únicamente `28` ya que en una condición O en cuanto una de las partes es cierta, el resultado es cierto independientemente del resto, y ya que `28` se considera `true`, obtendrás todos los registros, sin filtrado efectivo.

[Aquí puedes ver el resultado en línea.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s1vw8PgtGchtknsctGxPXm/0)

---

**Otro ejemplo para ilustrarte mejor el problema:**

```
idprincipal = 28 || 26 AND idfinal = 26
( idprincipal = 28 ) || 26 AND ( idfinal = 26 )
( idprincipal = 28 ) || ( 26 AND ( idfinal = 26 ) )
( idprincipal = 28 ) || ( idfinal = 26 )
```

Inicialmente podrías pensar que te va a mostrar los registros cuya `idprincipal` sea ( 28 *O* 26 ) *Y* la `idfinal` sea `26`, pero al final obtendrás los registros cuya `idprincipal` sea `28` *O* la `idfinal` sea `26`.

`( 26 AND ( idfinal = 26 ) )` se traduce en `( idfinal = 26 )` porque en una condición *Y* si uno de los operadores es cierto la condición depende únicamente del otro operador. En este caso `26` se considera cierto.

[Aquí tienes una versión online en la que puedes comprobar el resultado.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s1vw8PgtGchtknsctGxPXm/1)

Te recomiendo tener especial cuidado con la precedencia de operadores y, ante la duda, usar paréntesis para agruparlos.

Answer (score 1):

¿Estas usando SQL verdad?
Por lo tanto NO puedes usar `Limit`, en su lugar tienes el `Top`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM messages
WHERE
  idprincipal IN (28, 26)
AND
  idfinal IN (26, 28)
ORDER BY sent DESC
```

*Fuente: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp*

---

Si has usado `MYSQL`, como comentan en otras respuestas, has de usar `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE
  idprincipal IN (28, 26)
AND
  idfinal IN (26, 28)
ORDER BY sent DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: para el caso de `MYSQL`, se usa `LIMIT`, en caso de `SQL SEVER` se usa el `TOP`

Comment: ya ya, por eso, que el ha especificado el uso de "consulta SQL" y no "MYSQL". Por eso lo he puesto :) Si eso edito y añado tambien la sintaxis de MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

A lo que entiendo, para lo que quieres hacer puede utilizar:

```
SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY sent DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Para limitar el query a un sólo resultado mostrando siempre el más reciente. Así al momento de consultar tus resultados sólo aparecerá el mensaje más reciente. Para obtener todos los mensajes puedes utilizar un query diferente.

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE idprincipal = 28 DESC;
```